# Increasing memory consumption with creating and destroying qml windows

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, qml, qobject

I'm fairly new to QtQuick and have noticed a weird issue when creating and destroying windows. We have a large application that has many different complex windows, and I've noticed that when creating them they use a large amount of memory(several mbs) and when I destroy them memory consumption doesn't seem to go down at all. I just want to make sure I'm closing them correctly or if there is something else I should be doing instead. Maybe re-using them? Just looking for someone who is more experienced with QtQuick to give an explanation.

I've found a few posts from other people experiencing the same issue, but every answer seems to say that it stops eventually and I have yet to see this. We've used Sikuli in our application to rapidly open and close some of our windows and eventually it will use so much memory that it crashes the system.

I created a mini test app that demonstrates the issue I am experiencing. I'm not sure if this is a memory leak or just Qt allocating a large amount of memory up front to use, but it seems like the consumption never stops. I ran the below code and it eventually climbed up to 2 gigs of memory. I was just using task manager to monitor the memory usage, not any other tools.

ObjectCreator.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QObject>

class ObjectCreator : public QObject
{
   public:
      explicit ObjectCreator( QQmlApplicationEngine* engine );

   public slots:
      void createAndDestroyWindow() const;

   private:
      Q_OBJECT

      QQmlApplicationEngine* engine;
};
```

ObjectCreator.cpp

```
#include <QQmlComponent>
#include <QWindow>

#include "ObjectCreator.h"

ObjectCreator::ObjectCreator( QQmlApplicationEngine* engine ) :
   engine{ engine }
{
}

void ObjectCreator::createAndDestroyWindow() const
{
   QWindow* window = nullptr;

   QQmlComponent component( engine, QUrl( QString( "qrc:///Background.qml" ) ) );
   if ( component.status() == QQmlComponent::Ready )
      window = qobject_cast< QWindow* >( component.create() );

   if ( window != nullptr )
   {
      window->close();
      window->destroy();
   }
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include "ObjectCreator.h"

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
   QGuiApplication app( argc, argv );
   QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

   auto objectCreator = new ObjectCreator( &engine );
   engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty( "objectCreator", objectCreator );
   engine.load( QUrl( QStringLiteral( "qrc:/main.qml" ) ) );

   return app.exec();
}
```

Main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow
{
   id: mainWindow

   visible: true
   width: 200
   height: 200

   Timer
   {
      interval: 50
      running: true
      repeat: true

      onTriggered: objectCreator.createAndDestroyWindow();
   }
}
```

Background.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.3

Window
{
   id: backgroundWindowContainer

   height: Screen.height
   width: Screen.width

   Rectangle
   {
      id: backgroundRect

      anchors.fill: parent
   }
}
```

Edit: Forgot to add the code for the window I was creating/destroying.

Comment: What does valgrind say?

Comment: @Mitch I'm on Windows unfortunately.

Comment: Try heob: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-heob.html It has worked really well for me.

Comment: probably you have memory leak problem. are you delete pointer when you haven't any work with it?

Comment: show me how do you create and delete it...

Comment: @MohammadrezaPanahi - I was under the impression that destroy would delete it eventually. But even if I change the last line to "delete window" instead of "window->destroy()" it doesn't seem to change much.